# Increasing maximum preview column height in finder?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, preview, ventura

I use Columns the most in Finder since there's a lot of restrictions with Gallery view. It's much easier for me to see tags and a folder's entire contents in a list. But the maximum preview size in Columns is incredibly irritating.

First off, I've done everything possible to maximize the preview pane size within finder itself. I'm mostly looking to see if there's anything I can do in terminal to increase the maximum preview ***height*** in columns specifically.

As seen here, the preview pane stops resizing the selected image after a certain point, even though there's plenty of spare room. The actual image size is about twice the size of what is displayed in columns.

[image: Example]

It seems like the maximum preview height is determined by a set percentage of the column window size itself, **which appears to be ~50%. Ideally, I'd like that to be around 85%**. Does anyone know of a way to change that specific preview column size setting in terminal?

Comment: Why not just use Quicklook instead? that's what it's for.